# Can you run an auto-shutdown script for RStudio on Sagemaker?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, rstudio, amazon-sagemaker

In the past, I have run auto-shutdown scripts for Notebooks on Sagemaker. Currently we are using an RStudio session but I have not seen anything on if there is a way to suspend the session if it has been idle for "X" time.

Just curious if this is possible in Sagemaker lifecycle configurations.

Comment: I don't know if there's an automatic way to do it, but you can set up a scheduled shutdown with EventBridge and Lambda functions.

Comment: I’ve done it with the notebook instances but not sure if there is anything for the RStudio domain (or domains in general)

Comment: For JupyterLab based apps in domains, you can use this - https://github.com/aws-samples/sagemaker-studio-lifecycle-config-examples/tree/main/scripts/install-autoshutdown-server-extension
For RStudio apps, you can do the same scheduled start/stop by calling the CreateApp/DeleteApp API calls.